# Modify Work Item Workflow to check for dependencies?

Tags: tfs-workitem

I am using the TFS 2010 SCRUM template and was wondering if you can modify the task work item's workflow to not allow modifications in case a processor task is not yet done. Another option is to automatically set the state of a successor task to something so it cannot be changed until the processor tasks have been set to a specific state. Not sure if you can get this granular with the workflow.

Comment: Sure you want to do this with Scrum? You shouldn't be assuming you know which tasks will precede which other tasks.

Comment: Why not manage dependencies in SCRUM?

Comment: Because dependencies change so quickly. Why "manage" them? Leave it up to the team to decide which tasks should be performed in which order.

Comment: Manage is probably the wrong word. "Automating" TFS to determine task flow? I realize things can change rapidly. I am thinking of a way to let developers know, in an automated fasion, when a task is ready to be worked on becuase another task has finished.

Comment: doesn't sound like you understand Scrum. It's not up to anybody except the team to decide what they work on and when they work on it. They are responsible for committing to get the work done, and doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is a parent/child relationship you can build in 2010- I don't see anything in WorkFlow that would allow you to modify the Scrum WI templates to support this.

An alternative solution would be to make the WI only editable by the person who it is assigned to.  You can keep all your WIs assigned to a lead or PjM etc until the processor task is done and then assign it to the person in charge of the task.

```
<FieldDefinition reportable="dimension" refname="System.ChangedBy" name="Changed By" syncnamechanges="true" type="String">
  <COPY from="currentuser" />
  <FROZEN />
</FieldDefinition>
```

Aside from that, you may also consider a model where you cannot edit a WI until it is at a specific state.  For example, when X WI turns Active make everything editable and if it is still Proposed then make everything read-only using the WHENNOT clause.

And finally, why not consider just discussing these things in the daily scrum?  Team members should be on the same page about WIs.  Impediments are always going to come up and sometimes what you think the order of tasking will be at the beginning of the sprint planning is not how it turns out during the sprint.  A team task board can be very helpful to in order to discuss order etcetera.

Blocking devs or team members from modifying X item until Y item is complete where both X and Y are sprint backlog items assigned to a sprint may lead to more harm than good and ultimately detract from the ideals behind scrum (namely agility).  All that to say, before making this type of a modification make sure you absolutely need to.

Comment: The reason this came up is that we started making some tasks dependant on others. For example, we have tasks that are specification documents for online forms. Before the developers can build the form, the spec needs to be completed. I wanted a way to notify developers when Task A is done; they can begin work on Task B. What I may do is setup notification when certain task types are done. That may be a better way to work this.

Comment: Alerts would be a much better solution than modifying the template.  TFS Power Tools has many granular alerts you can add too.  Typically in Scrum the team hashes it out in a daily meeting which is why this type of request seemed odd but if this works best for your team and you have a hybrid approach to  Scrum than go for it.